# Spring Data Jpa Join with multiple table without @Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am newbie for Spring boot especially for Spring Boot Data JPA

I want to write JPA method without @Query

I know how to select through @Query 
However, there are no much about pure data JPA method
like

> Integer findByLevelPointBetweenSomethingAndSomething2(Integer userId);

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "point")
 public class Point {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "point_id", nullable = false)
private Integer pointId;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "point", nullable = false)
private Integer point;

@Column(name = "user_account_point_type_id", nullable = false)
private Integer pointTypeId;

@Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false)
private Date createdDate;
```

This is Point Entity which store point

and Level entity

```
 @Entity

 @Table(name = "level", schema = "public")
  public class Level {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "level_id", nullable = false)
private Integer levelId;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Integer userId;

@Column(name = "level_type_id", nullable = false)
@JoinColumn(name ="level_type_id")
private Integer levelTypeId;


@Column(name = "reg_date", nullable = false)
private Date regDate;
```

and level type is consisted as 4 type (1-bronze/2-silver/3-gold/4-platinum) 
i level type is checked when point is stored

and this is the query that i make

select ult.level_type_id from level_type ult where (select sum(up.point)
from level ull,point up,level_type ult
where ull.level_type_id=ult.level_type_id and ull.user_id=up.user_id and up.user_id= 73) between ult.level_start_point AND ult.level_end_point

result is level_type as Integer form

this query i want to make as JPA 
@Query() X!!!

LIKE THIS
    @Repository

```
 public interface LevelTypeRepository extends 
JpaRepository<LevelType,Integer> {

Integer findByLevelPointMaxBetweenLevelPointMinAndLevelPointMax(Integer 
userId);
```

}

However it is not working and don't know  how to join through three tables with one parameters
Moreover, parameter(user_id) between level_start_point and level_end_point

Is it difficult to express through JPA ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is not possible without @Query.

you have to go for either JPA QL or HQL.

Instead of the direct database table, it uses Java entity class which are mapped with database tables.

you are using table name in your query which is wrong.

Use the Entity class name instead of the table name and use the value of the entity's property instead of the table's column name.

For Example

```
@Query("SELECT l.levelId FROM Level l where l.userId = :uid")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does database has this join relationship i.e is there foreign_key Primary_Key relation in DB between the tables ? If yes, you can do it without using @Query annotation. If not, JPA will not join table by itself thus a custom query is required and @Query tag becomes necessary.